# Magento Bundle Product extremely slow

Tags: php, sql, performance, magento, bundle

I'm having a huge problem regarding Magento and the performance in huge bundles products.

The shop runs on a dedicated apache webserver, php5.4, 8gb ram, 3 cpu's, xcache activated.
I have ~3200 Simple Product including 10 Bundle Products which consists of the former.
One bundle product has arround 100 bundle options, ranging from 2 to 360 child-options to select (mostly 's).

Now, if I call the url, the loading time of that page is arronud 1:15 minutes!
Magento is still quite in its default state, no 3rd-company-modules which affect the product view.

Does anybody have any clou about how to fix that/inmprove the loading time?
Is Magento even capable of handling such a big bundle product? Maybe with a kind of special configuration?
Or could I say outsource the  and load them on click with ajax?
Unfortunately, I'm quite new to Magento - just for your info ;)

Thanks for any hint!
Best regards
Jan